# How can I pass value to iFrame with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I opened an iFrame in my page and onClick event try to send a value to the textbox of the iframe

This is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TextToFrame()
    {   
     var frame = frames['frame1'];
     frame.document.getElementById("u").value = "wallace";
    }
</script>
```

IFrame loads the page but when I click the Button , it doesn't send any value. 
It refreshes the main page and iFrame

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="TextToFrame();" Text="Send Value" />  

<IFRAME id="frame1" name="frame1" src="http://tweakers.net/my.tnet/login?location=http%3A%2F%2Ftweakers.net%2F" width=500px height=500px  runat="server">
```

What am I doing wrong?
any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the HTML in an iframe from a different domain. You might be able to change the iframe source to something like:

```
http://tweakers.net/my.tnet/login?u=wallace
```

but the site should give you an option like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution :

```
document.getElementsByName('frame1')[0].contentWindow.getElementById("u").value = "wallace";
```

Comment: I was not able to send value to textbox in the iframe.   I need to find another way obviously this wont go any further because I need to click the button as well later on

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate data inside an iframe which `src` attribute is different from the domain it's on.

Answer (score 0):

It won't allow you on cross-domain.

Have a look at this -[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Haroldis but one more thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TextToFrame()
    {   
     document.getElementsByName('frame1')[0].contentWindow.getElementById("u").value = "wallace";
     return false; // For No Post Back in the container Page 
    }
</script>
```

and the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return TextToFrame();" Text="Send Value" />
```

Comment: I guess I need to find another approach to my problem because I cant even enter text to places in iFrame, later on I am going to click Login buttons, redirect to other links etc