# how to Copy images from iframe into textarea?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i want to copy image from an iframe to div ot to textarea like this [jsfiddle.net/purmou/xEtL9/](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/xEtL9/)

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="content">
</textarea>

<div id="fake">
    <iframe width="100%" height="400px" src="http://www.w3schools.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

And

```
     $(function(){
            $("#fake iframe").click(function(){
                var update = $("<div>").append(
                    $("<iframe>").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"))
                ).html();

                $("#content").val(function( i, v ) {
                    return v + update;
                });
            });
        });
```

But for iframe it is not working..Any suggestion??

Comment: is this image your are trying to copy in content reside inside the iframe? if yes and ur domain is same you mentioned than i think its not possible..because this iframe is on another domain..see this post [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539756/how-can-i-pass-value-to-iframe-with-javascript)

Comment: "I don't think you can modify the HTML in an iframe from a different domain. " - not the same thing. you can read it fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This to do with the iframe not supporting onclick directly.

Discussed here: [Adding click event handler to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-onclick-event-to-iframe)

Basically it says you need to subscribe to the event via a listener to the iframe's document object:

> You can use closures to pass parameters:

```
iframe.document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {clic(this.id);}, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given id to your IFrame and have to use the IFrame id instead of <IFrame> tag.

Check below code

<iframe id="iframe1" width="100%" height="400px" src="http://www.w3schools.com/"/>

& $("iframe1").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"))

Happy coding!!!